# What is happening at the sub-atomic level to cause atoms to move? KE transfer from another atom is not relevant to the question

Tags: atomic-physics

Very specifically, I aim to understand the inner working mechanics of how the atom moves. Im not interested in KE being transferred from one atom to another (I know that this will increase movement). To give you an idea of what Im looking for in an answer:

---

I suppose that perhaps it could be electrons exciting up into upper orbitals and relaxing back down and that the relaxing back down to the lower orbital is a faster return than the excitation and this causes the atom to move in a singular direction. It would be similar to drawing back a hammer in your hand slowly, swinging it forward quickly and abruptly stopping it; your body would be propelled forward by the mass of the hammer. I know this idea has flaws.

---

This is just an idea to let you know what Im looking for. What are the actual physical mechanics which cause atomic movement. Im not interested in one atom transferring KE to another atom. Im interested in the inner workings of a single atom.
Does anyone know?

Comment: Why are you not interested in transfer of KE between atoms? Why do you think you need something else?

Comment: Because talking about transfer of KE is like telling me how car 1 hits car 2 and makes car 2 move. It doesnt address the combustion engine of the car which makes it move on a normal basis. The best idea that I had (and has been confirmed by a couple of people so far) is that it has to do with electron excitement and relaxation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is happening at the sub-atomic level to cause atoms to move? KE transfer from another atom is not relevant to the question

An atom, in our main stream physics model, is a quantum mechanical entity, has to be modeled with quantum mechanics at this sub-atomic level.

A single atom , with its quantum mechanically modeled sub atomic details, **cannot move.** It just sits in the center of mass system doing nothing, **unless** previously a quantum mechanical interaction had raised it to an excited state.

Observation and theory tells us that if it is an atomic excited state, it will relax down to a stable state by the emission of a photon. This means that for momentum conservation the atom will move opposite to the direction of the leaving photon, and in that sense a motion is induced.

If the nucleus is in an excited state , from the formation of the atom ( [nucleosynthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleosynthesis) ) in cosmological models, it might again just release one photon, acquiring a motion as in the atomic case,  or it may break down into smaller nuclei, and the atom, again by conservation of energy and momentum, may split in several particles and nuclei, acquiring  motions.

This is what measurements and observations have taught us, and the quantum mechanical models fit these observations.

Comment: Thanks Anna. The notion that photon emission is the "mechanical" aspect of atomic movement makes sense. If photons are being cast out of the atom in multiple directions by multiple electrons on various sides of the nucleus, would you happen to know why an atom travels in a straight direction rather than sporadically moving about in random directions?

Comment: @LotSaltpillr  When an atom is in an excited state, it may cascade down sequentially to the ground state stability. The "the sequentially"  is the important word, the process is not instantaneous., there is an energy width on each energy level  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Atomic/broaden.html . So , conservation of momentum will make the atom move in the various directions. The directions may be random or constrainr if the atom is bound in  a lattice.  I

Comment: f it is an electron there will only be one for each exciteds state and the interaction is more complicated, a photon should be absorbed for an electron to leave, and multiple of electrons would need multiple one to one interactions.

Comment: Thanks again Anna

Answer (score 4):

Atoms are not different than other objects.  They do not move on their own.  They move in response to outside forces/impulses/interactions or by sending some portion in one direction and the remainder in another.

> It would be similar to drawing back a hammer in your hand slowly, swinging it forward quickly and abruptly stopping it; your body would be propelled forward by the mass of the hammer.

Assuming the hammer did not strike something and remained in your hand, you would not be propelled at all.  The forces between your body and the hammer while accelerating it are reversed when decelerating.  You remain in place.  You could accelerate yourself by throwing the hammer, but you can only do this a finite number of times depending on how many hammers you have.

Atoms can be accelerated by external fields.  They will be pulled by gravity.  They can be given impulses from the electric fields of nearby atoms or by absorbing or scattering light.

An unstable or excited atom could decay.  The center of mass of the system would remain in place, but the daughter atom would be accelerated with respect to the other decay products.  (This includes decays that produce only photons).

Comment: While sitting in a chair with your back pressed to the back of the chair, take your fist and hold it up at eye level. Slowly move your fist forward then abruptly stop it. You will experience your back move away from the back of the chair (movement). Photon emission seems to be the consensus as to how atoms move. One thing that is not clear, however, is why there would be a straight line movement (as there are electrons around the whole nucleus, not just one side of the nucleus. Each of these electrons having the potential to release a photon in a different direction.

Comment: Your description only happens when there are external forces (friction).  If you performed it where other forces were not possible (isolated in space), then there would be no movement.  The slow movement is insufficient to overcome the friction in the wheels.

Comment: @LotSaltpillr it is important to retain that it is not electrons that release photons or absorb photons.  **the whole atom ** is involved in the energy momentum exchanges, the nucleus and electron being components of it.

Answer (score 0):

Photons are transferring energy through the photo electric effect. Not counting atoms, protons, neutrons or electrons, there’s only gravity left.